# why am I getting Error: Cannot find module '@google-cloud/firestore' if I have firestore in my dependencies?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm calling a firebase cloud function to create a stripe user, I'm getting this error in the logs "Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module '@google-cloud/firestore'" but I'm puzzled because I have firestore in my dependencies.

[image]

does anybody know how to fix it?

cloud function

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
//const firestore = require("@google-cloud/firestore");
const { Configuration, PlaidApi, PlaidEnvironments } = require("plaid");
const stripe = require("stripe")(
  "sk_stripe"
);
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();
const auth = admin.auth();

//create stripe customer
exports.createStripeUser = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const phoneNum = data.phone;
  const uid = context.auth.uid;

  if (uid === null) {
    console.log("Illegal access attempt due to unauthenticated attempt.");
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError("internal", "Illegal access attempt");
  }

  return stripe.customers
    .create({ phone: phoneNum })
    .then((customer) => {
      return customer["id"];
    })
    .then((customerId) => {
      
      admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(uid).set({
        stripeId: customerId,
        phone: phoneNum,
        id: uid,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        "internal",
        " Unable to create Stripe user : " + err
      );
    });
});
```

dependencies
[image]

thanks

Comment: 1. Are you sure, that there is a folder "firestore" in node_modules/@google-cloud/ ?
2. You declare "const firestore" but you dont use it anywhere in your code. U can access firestore via "admin.firestore" or "functions.firestore"

Comment: Hi @Nat Serrano, Have you tried deleting your entire nodes_modules folder and install your packages from scratch?